# Apache 2 basic reverse proxy config not working, getting 404 error

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, proxy, reverse-proxy, apache2

I started a new server in a virtual machine, and I can access its homepage from the browser. I set up a docker container hosted on port 90 which I can also access. To link `/app/` to `localhost:90` I enabled the `proxy` module and edited `000-default.conf` to the following configuration following the oficial documentation:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


    ProxyRequests off
    <Proxy *>
      ProxyPreserveHost Off <- I tried On
      Require all granted
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass /app/ http://localhost:90/ <- I tried without trailing slashes on both arguments and lines. (I get 500 response without them)
    ProxyPassReverse /app/ http://localhost:90/

</VirtualHost>
```

When opening `localhost/app` from the vm or the same route from outside I get 404 error. What could be wrong here?

`apache2ctl -S` output:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

No errors on error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was typing `localhost/app` where it should be `localhost/app/`... Yeah,  I know.